# Picking a random element from a hash set

Tags: objective-c, performance, data-structures, random, set

I need a collection with the following requirements (in Objective C if that matters):

1. constant time insertions
2. constant time deletions
3. get number of elements
4. ***constant time get random element***

A hash set would work, but the NSMutableSet class is abstract.  I don't know how the NSMutableSet class is written, but I figured a hash set which dynamically grows/shrinks would be suitable as the load ratio would have a guaranteed range, and therefore a random element functionality could be implemented by randomly selecting a bucket and iterating through buckets until a nonempty bucket is found, then selecting a random element from that bucket.  This would be great as it would make selecting a random element constant time, however I do not want to reinvent the wheel.  Does anyone have any suggestions, or libraries to point me to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any limitations to number and order of the operations?

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon the same problem. here is what i came up with

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

unordered_set<int> u;
int ins = 0;
for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {   // something to fill the test set
    ins += i;
    ins %= 73;
    u.insert(ins);
}
cout << "total number of buckets: " << u.bucket_count() << endl;
for(size_t b=0; b<u.bucket_count(); b++)      //showing how the set looks like
    if (u.bucket_size(b)) {
        cout << "Bucket " << b << " contains: ";
        unordered_set<int>::local_iterator lit;
        for (lit = u.begin(b);  lit != u.end(b);) {
            cout << *lit;
            if (++lit != u.end(b))
                cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
cout << endl;

int r = rand() % u.bucket_count();

while (u.bucket_size(r) == 0)         // finding nonempty bucket 
    r = (r + 1) % u.bucket_count();   // modulo is here to prevent overflow

unordered_set<int>::local_iterator lit = u.begin(r);

if (u.bucket_size(r) > 1) {              // if bucket has more elements then
    int r2 = rand() % u.bucket_size(r);  // pick randomly from them
    for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++)
        lit++;
}
cout << "Randomly picked element is " << *lit << endl;
cin.ignore();

return 0;
}
```

Now for the rehashing problems:

1. If your set is growing then it is on default rehashed after its elements/buckets ratio is greater than one. So my solution is safe here.
2. However if your set grows and then rapidly shrinks there is no rehashing until the set is empty so you may want to perform the check and eventually rehash.

   if (u.load_factor() < 0.1)
        u.rehash(u.size());

This checks if the set is at least 10% full and if not then rehashes so the size of set is appropriate for storing current number of elements. (usually new size equals to smaller power of 2 which is greater than size)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `constant` is actually `log n`, I recommend rolling up your own **[B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)**. Then you have:

```
- (id)randomObject {
    Your_Branch_Type* branch = your_root;
    NSUInteger randomIndex = RANDOM_INTEGER_UP_TO(count);
    while (!branch.final)
        if (branch.left.count >= randomIndex) {
            branch = branch.left; 
        } else {
            branch = branch.right;
        }
    return branch.object;
}
```